# distance computation in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to do a distance computation are mark only those points which satisfies the given condition. More specifically, let p=(1,1,1) and I want to put a solid circle at only those points (x,y,z) which satisfies |1-x| + |1-y| + |1-z| = 1.... [image]

I could do manually as well, but if a general method is available it is better to use. Here is the code I'm working on:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\begin{document}


\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{125}
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{0}{0} %<- rotate around (z,y,z)

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.0]

\foreach \x in {0,1,2}
   \foreach \y in {0,1,2}
     \foreach \z in {0,1,2}{
       %#####################################################
       \ifthenelse{  \lengthtest{\x pt < 2pt}  }
       {
         % True
            \draw [black]   (\x,\y,\z) -- (\x+1,\y,\z);
       }
       {% False
       }
       %#####################################################
       \ifthenelse{  \lengthtest{\y pt < 2pt}  }
       {
         % True
            \draw [black]   (\x,\y,\z) -- (\x,\y+1,\z);
       }
       {% False
       }
       %#####################################################
       \ifthenelse{  \lengthtest{\z pt < 2pt}  }
       {
         % True
            \draw [black]   (\x,\y,\z) -- (\x,\y,\z+1);
       }
       {% False
       }
       \draw (\x,\y,\z) circle(2pt); 

}



 \filldraw[fill opacity=0.3, draw=gray, fill=gray!20]
 (0,0,1)--(2,0,1)--(2,2,1)--(0,2,1)--cycle;

 \fill[black] (1,1,2) circle(2pt);
 \fill[black] (2,1,1) circle(2pt);
 \fill[black] (1,1,0) circle(2pt);
 \fill[black] (0,1,1) circle(2pt);

 \filldraw[fill opacity=0.3, draw=gray, fill=gray!20]
 (0,1,2)--(2,1,2)--(2,1,0)--(0,1,0)--cycle;

 \fill[black] (1,0,1) circle(2pt);
 \fill[black] (1,2,1) circle(2pt);



  \node[below right] at (1,1,1){$p$};
   \fill[black] (1,1,1) circle(1pt);

\end{tikzpicture}

 \end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `\pgfmathparse{int(abs(1-\x)+abs(1-\y)+abs(1-\z))}` to compute your distance and then `\ifnum\pgfmathresult=1` to test for distance `1`. Similarly, I'd use `\ifnum\x<1` etc instead of `\ifthenelse...` just because is it shorter.

With these changes your MWE becomes marginally shorter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{125}
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{0}{0} %<- rotate around (z,y,z)

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.0]

  \foreach \x in {0,1,2}
     \foreach \y in {0,1,2}
       \foreach \z in {0,1,2}{i
         \pgfmathparse{int(abs(1-\x)+abs(1-\y)+abs(1-\z))}
         \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
           \fill[black] (\x,\y,\z) circle(2pt);
         \else
           \draw (\x,\y,\z) circle(2pt);
         \fi
         %#####################################################
         \ifnum\x<2
              \draw [black]   (\x,\y,\z) -- (\x+1,\y,\z);
         \fi
         %#####################################################
         \ifnum\y<2
              \draw [black]   (\x,\y,\z) -- (\x,\y+1,\z);
         \fi
         %#####################################################
         \ifnum\z<2
              \draw [black]   (\x,\y,\z) -- (\x,\y,\z+1);
         \fi
  }

  \filldraw[fill opacity=0.3, draw=gray, fill=gray!20]
  (0,0,1)--(2,0,1)--(2,2,1)--(0,2,1)--cycle;

  \filldraw[fill opacity=0.3, draw=gray, fill=gray!20]
  (0,1,2)--(2,1,2)--(2,1,0)--(0,1,0)--cycle;

  \node[below right] at (1,1,1){$p$};
  \fill[black] (1,1,1) circle(1pt);

\end{tikzpicture}

 \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The output is the same.

Answer (score 3):

This solution is very similar to Andrew's solution, i also used `\ifnum` instead of `\ifthenelse` and the computation is quite the same.

But i added two variables `\newcommand\MaxSize{CubeSize}` and `\def\P{{P_x,P_y,P_z}}` to define the cube size and the point P to. Also some code is added to have a more general method to create the gray plains or the point P.

***Example with `\def\P{{1,1,1}}` and `MaxSize =1,...,3`(see first for loop):***
[image]

***distance-computation:***

```
\pgfmathparse{abs(\P[0]-\x)+abs(\P[2]-\y)+abs(\P[2]-\z)-1}
\ifcase\pgfmathresult 
        \draw[fill] (\x,\y,\z) circle(2pt); 
 \else 
         \draw (\x,\y,\z) circle(2pt);  
\fi
```

- ifcase:  those points (x,y,z) which satisfy`|1-x| + |1-y| + |1-z| -1= 0`=> filled
- else: those points (x,y,z) which satisfy`|1-x| + |1-y| + |1-z| -1~= 0` => not filled

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} 
\usepackage{xifthen}

\newcommand\MaxSize{2}
\def\P{{1,1,1}}

\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{125}
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{0}{0}

\foreach \size in {1,...,3}{

\renewcommand\MaxSize{\size}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,\MaxSize}
    \foreach \y in {0,1,...,\MaxSize}
        \foreach \z in {0,1,...,\MaxSize}{

         \ifnum\x<\MaxSize
            \draw [black]   (\x,\y,\z) -- (\x+1,\y,\z);
         \fi

        \ifnum\y<\MaxSize
            \draw [black]   (\x,\y,\z) -- (\x,\y+1,\z);
        \fi

        \ifnum\z<\MaxSize
            \draw [black]   (\x,\y,\z) -- (\x,\y,\z+1);
        \fi

\pgfmathparse{abs(\P[0]-\x)+abs(\P[2]-\y)+abs(\P[2]-\z)-1}
\ifcase\pgfmathresult 
        \draw[fill] (\x,\y,\z) circle(2pt); 
 \else 
         \draw (\x,\y,\z) circle(2pt);  
\fi

}

\filldraw[fill opacity=0.3, draw=red, fill=gray!20](0,0,\P[2])--(\MaxSize,0,\P[2])--(\MaxSize,\MaxSize,\P[2])--(0,\MaxSize,\P[2])--cycle;

\filldraw[fill opacity=0.3, draw=red, fill=gray!20] (0,\P[1],\MaxSize)--(\MaxSize,\P[1],\MaxSize)--(\MaxSize,\P[1],0)--(0,\P[1],0)--cycle;

%Point P
\node[below right,green] at (\P[0],\P[1],\P[2]){$p$};
\fill[green] (\P[0],\P[1],\P[2]) circle(1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for the `\P[i]`. I didn't know that this was possible!